# Cannot Use the Wireless Hosted Network Feature on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, internet-sharing

I have 2 pc's. One of them have a broadband internet connection. Now for the second pc I connect it wirelessly to the first through a wireless USB adapter. I set up the the first pc to act as a proxy server and use it for internet sharing to the second. So far so good.

Now I have an android phone which I would also like to connect to internet through the second pc. I know my D-link wireless usb adapter supports `Wireless Hosted Network` i.e. it can be a `Hotspot` as well as a `client` simultaneosly. 
I started the hosted network using these commands

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Test key=abcd1234`

`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

Running these commands shows up the `Microsoft Virtual Wifi Miniport adapter` in Network Connections. The hosted network is visible and connectible from the phone.

The problem is I cannot connect to these two wifi connections simultaneously, i.e. If I first connect to the pc wifi network and then start the wireless hosted network then the pc network disconnects. Reverse happens the other way round.

I have read that is is possible to virtualize a physical network adapter into two virtual ones and use them simultaneously. However it is not working in my case. I would like to know what can be the solution ?

EDIT:
When I run the
`netsh wlan show drivers` command , I get the following output

```
Interface name: Wireless Network Connection

    Driver                    : D-Link DWA-125 Wireless N 150 USB Adapter(rev.A2
)
    Vendor                    : D-Link Corporation
    Provider                  : D-Link Corporation
    Date                      : 28-04-2011
    Version                   : 3.2.1.0
    INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\oem52.inf
    Files                     : 4 total
                                C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\Dnetr28u.sys
                                C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
                                C:\Windows\system32\RaCoInst.dll
                                C:\Windows\system32\RaCoInst.dat
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    Hosted network supported  : Yes
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                Shared          WEP-40bit
                                Shared          WEP-104bit
                                Shared          WEP
                                WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                                WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                                WPA-Personal    TKIP
                                WPA-Personal    CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Vendor defined  TKIP
                                Vendor defined  CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                                WPA2-Enterprise Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
    Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP-40bit
                                Open            WEP-104bit
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
```

Comment: try the Ralink RT2870 driver from here: http://www.station-drivers.com/page/ralink.htm. This is the latest driver I can find. In the .inf I see your card as supported device.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That was definitely the latest driver, but installing it did not fixed the issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, for providing me the link to the latest driver, previously I was using the old d-link drivers that came bundled with the cd. The new driver enabled a lot of new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of research, I figured this out myself.

The reason I could not connect to the two wifi networks simultaneously was that the pc to pc network was a ad-hoc network and the pc to mobile network was an infrastructure one. So I think that one could not connect two different network types at the same time. What I did was change the pc to pc network type to infrastructure mode, and then I could connect the mobile to the second pc, and everything worked no disconnection problem.